# Two objects with same materials, modifiers and lighting are different

Tags: texturing, shaders

What the title says. I have multicolor bubble materials in one project that look like bubbles. I have another project where I'm trying to recreate the material and it kind of looks like a clear bubble with some dark in the middle and it won't change color. I've tried comparing and redoing the textures a dozen times by now and they won't match up.

Can anyone spot the difference?

Broken Bubble

[image]

[image]

Multicolor Bubbles

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can append the material from one file to the other and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you! That did help. I'm still gonna try to get an answer to my question, but this will at least help me to move on.

Comment: Hello, we shouldn't have to download multiple blend files to answer your question, it should stand on its own. Please add screenshots of your interface instead of links to your work files

Comment: @MartinMarino Yes (agree with Gorgious) please next time add screens of issue and how it should looks like ... blend files are very helpful, but screens gives as quick understanding what are you looking for and they can speedup issue hunting. Your time / Our time. Thank you.

Comment: @Gorgious Almost everytime I add screenshots, people ask me for blend files. But sure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Material Properties > Settings > Blend Mode > Opaque* change to **Alpha Blend**

[image]

Opaque
[image]

Alpha Blend
[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works